# JavaScript source code for Color Generator isn't working

Tags: javascript, function, code-generation, color-palette

I've coded a Color Palette Generator with JavaScript, Html and CSS. My JavaScript source code to make the Color Palette Generator actually generate color palettes isn't working.

https://github.com/tzanders711/Color-Palette-Generator-/blob/bff2810d1315442cfb52992b4ccedc2e748ab46e/myscripts.js

```
const colorCard = document.querySelectorAll(".colorCards1", ".colorCards2", ".colorCards3", ".colorCards4", ".colorCards5");

const buttonElement = document.getElementById("btn");

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {

     if (e.key === ' ') {

      generatePalette();

  }

 document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", generatePalette);

     function generatePalette() {

    colorCard.forEach(colorCard => {

       const newColor = generatePalette();

       });

       

        colorCard.querySelector(".colorCards1", ".colorCards2", ".colorCards3", ".colorCards4", ".colorCards5").style.background = newColor;

        colorCard.querySelector("p").innerText = newColor;

    }

});

       function generatePalette() {

        const letters = ['0','1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

        

        let color = '#';

       

        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];

          }

          

          return color;

       }
```

I moved my JavaScript code to the bottom of my code just above the  tag and added an async attribute to my JavaScript opening tag so that my html document will load before my JavaScript code.

I'm not getting any Type of SyntaxErrors. I can only guess that something is wrong with the code because what I have doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You had syntax and logical errors in your code.You had `generatePalette` defined twice, whereas one function should generate random color and other the pallete etc. `document.querySelectorAll` accepts one string argument. To select multiple selectors, don't enclose every single selector in separate quotes. Use one quote for all `const colorCards = document.querySelectorAll(".colorCards1, .colorCards2, .colorCards3, .colorCards4, .colorCards5");`. Here is fixed version:

```js
const colorCards = document.querySelectorAll(".colorCards1, .colorCards2, .colorCards3, .colorCards4, .colorCards5");


function generateRandomColor() {
  const letters = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  let color = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function generatePallete() {
  colorCards.forEach(card => {
    const newColor = generateRandomColor();
    card.style.background = newColor;
    card.querySelector("p").innerText = newColor;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === ' ') {
   generatePallete();
  }
});

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  generatePallete();
});
```

```css
*{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 .flex-container{
     display: flex;
}
 .colorCards1{
     flex-direction: row;
     background: 14px #d8b4fe;
     border: 30px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 240px;
     margin-top: 40px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
 .colorCards2{
     flex-direction: row;
     background: 14px #c084fc;
     border: 30px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 240px;
     margin-top: 40px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
 .colorCards3{
     flex-direction: row;
     background: 14px #a855f7;
     border: 30px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 240px;
     margin-top: 40px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
 .colorCards4{
     flex-direction: row;
     background: 14px #9333ea;
     border: 30px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 240px;
     margin-top: 40px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
 .colorCards5{
     flex-direction: row;
     background: 14px #7e22ce;
     border: 30px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
     height: 240px;
     margin-top: 40px;
     margin-left: 20px;
     margin-right: 20px;
}
 p{
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: bold;
     justify-content: center;
     margin-top: 245px;
}
 h1{
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 100px;
}
 body{
     background-color: #cccccc;
     position: absolute;
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 button{
     margin-left: 500px;
     margin-top: 50px;
     margin-right: 500px;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 15px 25px;
     font-size: 24px;
     cursor: pointer;
     text-align: center;
     justify-content: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     outline: none;
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #ca5cdd;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 15px;
     box-shadow: 0 9px #b39bd8;
}
 .button:hover {
     background-color: #be2ed6;
}
 .button:active {
     background-color: #be2ed6;
     box-shadow: 0 5px #b39bd8;
     transform: translateY(4px);
}
 .flex-containter div:hover {
     background-color: none;
}
 .flex-container div:active {
     background-color: none;
     box-shadow: 0 3px #BEBEBE;
     transform: translateY(-6px);
     transition: transform;
}
```

```html
   
       
        <h1>Color Palette Generator</h1>
    
        <div class="flex-container" onclick="hover()" id="container">
            <div class="colorCards1" id="colorCard">
                <p id="innerText">#d8b4fe</p>
             </div>
             <div class="colorCards2" id="colorCard">
                <p id="innerText">#c084fc</p>
             </div>
             <div class="colorCards3" id="colorCard">
                <p id="innerText">#a855f7</p>
             </div>
             <div class="colorCards4" id="colorCard">
                <p id="innerText">#9333ea</p>
             </div>
             <div class="colorCards5" id="colorCard">
                <p id="innerText">#7e22ce</p>
             </div>
       </div>
    
    <button class="button" id="btn">Generate Palette</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you really helped me out! Your code worked but now it's giving me this TypeError in the JavaScript console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener').

Comment: There is no such error in my code. The error msg suggests that you are trying to attach event listener to non-existent element. Check your HTML it should contain `<button id="btn">`.